# Javascript POO : Na Hora de Validar o Campo Aluno se é vazio, ele pula da condicional se e vai diretamente para a se não

Tags: javascript

```js
class MediaAluno {
 constructor(){
   this.Aluno = "";
   this.Nota1 =  "";
   this.Nota2 =  "";
   this.Nota3 =  "";
   this.Nota4 =  "";
   this.soma;
   this.resultado;
 }

 ResultadoMedia(){
   if(this.Aluno = ""){
     alert("O Campo Aluno não pode ser vazio !!")

   }else{
     alert("TUDO OK !!")
   }
 }
}

medias = new MediaAluno()
```

```css
.formulario{
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 450px;
margin-right: 450px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 3px;
border:2px solid green;
}
.titulo{
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: italic;
}
.Peso{
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px; 
}
.Notas{
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px; 
}
.Altura{
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;  
}
#formatacao{
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.lado{
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.botao{
  border:2px solid red;
  border-radius:4px; 
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight:bolder;
  font-size:16px;
  padding:5px 20px;
  color: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.resetar{
  border:2px solid red;
  border-radius:4px; 
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight:bolder;
  font-size:16px;
  padding:5px 20px;
  color: red;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;

}
.campo{
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin: 0px 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Media dos Alunos</title>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- ESSA PARTE É DO HTML -->
  <section class="formulario">
    <h3 class="titulo">Media do Aluno(a)</h3>
   <form method="POST" id="media" action="index.html">
     <div class="Notas">
       <label>Aluno(a)</label>
       <input type="text" name="Aluno" id="Aluno">
     </div>
     <div class="Notas">
      <label>Nota 1º</label>
      <input type="text" name="Nota1" id="Nota1">
    </div>
    <div class="Notas">
      <label>Nota 2º</label>
      <input type="text" name="Nota2" id="Nota2">
    </div>
    <div class="Notas">
      <label>Nota 3º</label>
      <input type="text" name="Nota3" id="Nota3">
    </div>
    <div class="Notas">
      <label>Nota 4º</label>
      <input  type="text" name="Nota4" id="Nota4">
    </div>
    
    <div class="lado">
      <input class="botao" type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick="medias.ResultadoMedia()">
    </div>
   </form> 
  </section>
  
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dentro do if você fez uma atribuição. Quando na verdade deveria testar a igualdade.

Comment: Atribuição é assim: `const a = 1`.  Quando desejamos verificar a igualdade usamos um operador lógico. Poder ser a igualdade estrita `a === 1` ou igualdade ampla `a == "1"`. [Para mais informações](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).

Answer (score -1):

Então, você está errando no if.
Você ta fazendo `if(this.Aluno = "")`, o que essencialmente é uma atribuição de valor e não uma checagem, você está tentando atribuir o valor '' à this.Aluno dentro do if. Para você checar de `this.Aluno` é uma string vazia você deve usar `if(this.Aluno === ''`), por que assim o JS checa os valores e tipos da igualdade.

Answer (score -1):

O erro está dentro do comando condicional. Não tem relação com o fato de ser POO.

Veja o que fez:

```
if(this.Aluno = ""){
     alert("O Campo Aluno não pode ser vazio !!")
}
```

Verifique que dentro do comando condicional `if` você está fazendo uma tribuição.

Quando na verdade gostaria de fazer uma comparação. Segue o exemplo:

```
if (this.Aluno === "") {
    alert("O Campo Aluno não pode ser vazio !!")
}
```

Em javascript existe a comparação estrita e a comparação ampla, veja a diferença

#### Igualdade ampla

Igualdade ampla compara dois valores para a igualdade, após converter ambos os valores para um tipo comum (um ou ambos os lados da comparação podem sofrer conversões).

Por exemplo:

```
const a = 123
const b = "123"
typeof(a)
// "number"
typeof(b)
// "string"
if (a == b) {
    console.log("iguais")
}
```

Repare que neste tipo de igualdade apesar dos tipos serem diferentes recebemos o resultado esperado.

#### Igualdade estrita

Utilizando a igualdade estrita, teríamos:

```
const a = 123
const b = 123
typeof(a)
// "number"
typeof(b)
// "number"
if (a === b) {
    console.log("iguais")
}
```

Para saber mais consulte a [`documentação`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).